# Can I tweak Openshift's haproxy.cfg using a file in my scalable app's git repository?

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I would like to maintain some haproxy.cfg customizations for my scalable OpenShift application in git, and have Openshift pick up and use my settings on deployment.

Is this possible?

I know that Openshift generates the haproxy settings in that file. Ideally I would be able to change the httpchk url or disable the public haproxy-status page, and have Openshift merge my config with the server-provided settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is a bit old, but maybe it will help someone else.
You can use `rhc scp` command to download and upload any file to your main gear:

- download the file from your gear: `rhc scp APPNAME download . haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg`
- edit it
- upload the file back to your gear:
  `rhc scp APPNAME upload haproxy.cfg haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg`

You can also:

- add your haproxy configuration file to your git repo (e.g. `conf/haproxy.cfg`)
- add an [action hook](https://developers.openshift.com/managing-your-applications/action-hooks.html) script to your `.openshift/action_hooks` git directory (e.g. pre_reload, pre_restart) like so:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  cp $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/conf/haproxy.cfg ~/haproxy/conf/haproxy.cfg
  ```
- Don't forget to make it executable (`git update-index --chmod=+x .openshift/action_hooks/*`)

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting this with a detailed answer!

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do that

- SSH into your application gear using `rhc ssh --app <app_name>`
- Change directory to `haproxy/conf`
- change the following in haproxy.cfg `option httpchk GET /` to option `httpchk GET /api/v1/ping`
- Restart the HAProxy cartridge from your local machine using RHC `rhc cartridge-restart --cartridge haproxy`

For more read my blog https://www.openshift.com/blogs/how-to-host-your-java-ee-application-with-auto-scaling

Comment: I was aware that I could do this. I was just wondering if there was a way to set it up without ssh-ing in.

Comment: @Shekhar thanks for `option httpchk GET / to option httpchk GET /api/v1/ping`

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create a symlink in place of the haproxy.cfg to point to the file you wanted to use in your ~/app-root/repo directory.  However, I have not tested this and am not sure if it would work or not.  Make sure to let us know if it works.